# SparkR Cartesian joins causes error - trying to get date sequence

Tags: r, join, sequence, sparkr, cartesian

Has anyone had success in doing a cartesian join between a sparkR DataFrame and a DataFrame converted from an R data.frame?

I have a sparkR DataFrame (spark_df) that I pull in from an outside source - I apologize that I don't know how to provide a reproducible example of having data already in spark but not having previously converted from R.  I created a test R data frame with just one entry and converted it to a Spark data frame then try to join:

`test_df = data.frame(month_dates = '2015-11-01')
t_dates = createDataFrame(sql, test_df)
lpd = join(spark_df, t_dates)
showDF(lpd)`

In reply, I get a slew of error messages ending in:

```
16/09/08 20:46:02 ERROR RBackendHandler: showString on 3363 failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) : 
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1643.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1643.0 (TID 17015, prod-mesos-s-6.aws.company.com): org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
 7f5a022f3000-7f5a022f4000 rw-p 0182a000 ca:01 16926                      /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.54.1
7f5a022f4000-7f5a0231a000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 4839                       /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f5a0231a000-7f5a02519000 ---p 00026000 ca:01 4839                       /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f5a02519000-7f5a0251d000 r--p 00025000 ca:01 4839                       /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f5a0251d000-7f5a0251e000 rw-p 00029000 ca:01 4839                       /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f5a0251e000-7f5a02534000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 11293                      /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-5.3.1-20160406.so.1
7f5a02534000-7f5a02733000 ---p 00016000 ca:01 11293                      /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-5.3.1-20160
```

My end goal is a sequence of dates given a start date and end date so that I can fill in missing dates in t-dates.  I couldn't figure out a way to do sequences in SparkR which is why I was doing it in R and converting to SparkR DataFrame - if there is a better way to do this using SparkR that avoids data.frames altogether, that would be rad.

If anyone knows how to fix this issue, that would also be rad.

Session Info:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Fedora 22 (Twenty Two)    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] SparkR_1.6.1    lubridate_1.5.6 zoo_1.7-12      dplyr_0.4.3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] lazyeval_0.2.0  magrittr_1.5    R6_2.1.2        assertthat_0.1 
 [5] parallel_3.3.0  tools_3.3.0     DBI_0.4-1       Rcpp_0.12.7    
 [9] stringi_1.1.1   grid_3.3.0      stringr_1.0.0   lattice_0.20-33
```